# Conditioning on Random Variable and Event Simultaneously + Law of Iterated Expectations.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X, Y, Z$ are random variables that live on $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ and $A\in \mathscr{F}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A) >0$. My first question is formally what does the conditional expectation:

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}\left[ X | Z, A\right]
\end{equation*}

actually mean?

I understand that $\mathbb{E}\left[ X|A\right] = \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[ X1_A\right]}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$ and I also understand that $\mathbb{E}\left[ X | Z\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ X | \sigma(Z)\right]$ is formally defined via the kolmogorov definition) to be a $\sigma(Z)$-measurable random variable such that

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbb{E}\left[ X | Z\right] 1_E\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ X1_E\right] \qquad \forall E\in \sigma(Z)
\end{equation*}

So what does it mean for when you condition on both an event $A$ and a random variable $Z$? Is this well defined in some way?

I am asking this first question in order to understand whether or not I can then use the towering property to see why it is the case that I can write something as follows:

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}\left[ X | Y= y\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbb{E}\left[ X | Z, Y = y\right]| Y = y\right]
\end{equation*}

(At least I think I can write something like that....hopefully it is true!). If this second statement above is true, then could you please show how you prove it rigorously via the definition of the kolmogorov expectation?

Many thanks.

Comment: You can rewrite the conditioning on event A as conditioning on the random variable that is the indicator for event A. Then, you can treat $\mathbb{1_A},Z$ as one RV is the first part; the second part sounds right but let me actually do it. (Side note: then look at the outcome of the conditional on the event A.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure $E[X|A] = E[X|1_A]$ is NOT true.... The thing on the left is constant and the thing on the right is a random variable (which is definitely not a constant) to my knowledge....I agree though that $E[X|1_A] = E[X|\sigma(A)]$.

Comment: Yeah, that is why I added the side note; you just look at its value on that particular event.

Comment: Ah right - got it!

Comment: You can think of it this way, $\sigma(A)$ is the same thing as $\sigma(\mathbb{1}_A)$

Answer (score 1):

I find it much more useful to rewrite the conditioning on event A as conditioning on the random variable that is the indicator for event A (and then evaluating the resulting conditional on the said event), since the measure-theoretic definition of conditional expectation is well-defined for $\sigma$-algebras, and not individual events.

I argue that $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Z, Y] \mid Y]  = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Z, Y=y]]$ on $\{Y=y\}$, since the right hand side is a function of $y$, and that is measurable w.r.t $Y$ by definition of $Y$ ($\{y\}$ is a Borel set). They agree on this particular set since integrating over $
 \{Y=y\}$, $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Z, Y]\mathbb{1}_{\{Y=y\}}] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Z, Y=y]\mathbb{1}_{\{Y=y\}}]$. (To see it, you can write $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Z, Y] = h(Z,Y)$, and now when you integrate over only the event $\{Y=y\}$, you can replace that by $h(Z,y)$, also $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X]]$ = $\mathbb{E}[X]$).

I think this argument is right, but I would definitely want someone to double check it.

Comment: Hi @E-A. Thank you for your prompt answer. Let me digest what you have written!

I think the main step I am trying to struggle with is why you're essentially saying that it is sufficient to prove $E[E[X|Z , Y]|Y] = E[E[X|Z, Y = y]]$ on the set ${Y = y}$ in order prove the statement $E[X|Y=y]=E[E[X|Z,Y=y]|Y=y]$.

Comment: Yeah, I think so; again, I would double check with your professor if you are taking this class (I will probably double check with mine on Thursday); will keep you posted.

Comment: Thanks @E-A. Will look forward to hearing from you then.

Comment: I checked it yesterday; yeah; I think as long as you check it on $\{ Y = y\}$, it should be enough.

Comment: Technically, you should check it on $\{ Y \not = y\}$ in the sigma-algebra case but since you only care about the output of the RV when they are equal, you should be fine.